# When will we get the new user pages stackoverflow has?

Tags: discussion

A few weeks ago, stackoverflow got some nifty new user pages.

I was wondering when will we get them over here at GDSE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't find a timeline, but there is a progress list: [List of communities with base css updates completed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253359/list-of-communities-with-base-css-updates-completed)

They started rolling out the update two weeks ago, and they're about half done, so I'd guess we'll get them within the next two weeks. But without a timeline, who knows.